# Show PopupWindow 3 seconds after Activity is created and last 3 seconds

Tags: android, popupwindow

I have  popup window in activity. What I want is that this popup starts after 3 seconds when activity is created and last for 3 seconds. Any help please?

here is my code:

```
try {
    LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // Inflate the view from a predefined XML layout
    View layout = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.activity_pop_up,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutZaFragment));
    // create a 300px width and 470px height PopupWindow
    pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 470, true);
    // display the popup in the center
    pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
boolean isShowing=false;
```

In onCreate

```
    CountDownTimer timer=new CountDownTimer(3000,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if(isShowing){
                //CLOSE
            }
            else{
            isShowing=true;
            LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater)
                    MainActivity.this
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //Inflate the view from a predefined XML layout
            View layout = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.activity_pop_up,
                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutZaFragment));
            // create a 300px width and 470px height PopupWindow
            pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 470, true);
            // display the popup in the center
            pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
            timer.start();
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
```

Comment: i cant implent this in oncreate() method.

Comment: The boolean is showing above on create, and the rest in the on create

Comment: When i implement this popup is constantly on screen, i needd to dismiss it somehow

Comment: You should add some explanation to your code too, so the SO can learn something.

Comment: @smilijka add your code to close the popup where the comment //CLOSE

Comment: Try now, i made a mistake

Comment: Have you added the timer.start(); in the else?

Comment: I added pw.dismiss(); in  @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if(isShowing){
                //CLOSE
            } but still running?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142653/discussion-between-smiljka-and-martin-de-simone).

Comment: timer.start(); is accesed from iner class. when i make it global, and add ,popup is still running without canceling...

Answer (score 0):

That can be easily implemented with posting an event on `Handler`.

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
private PopupWindow popupWindow;

private final Runnable dismissPopupRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // dismiss popupWindow
    }
};

private final Runnable showPopupRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // show popupWindow
        handler.postDelayed(dismissPopupRunnable, 3000);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // initialize popupWindow here

    handler.postDelayed(showPopupRunnable, 3000);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    handler.removeCallbacks(showPopupRunnable);
    handler.removeCallbacks(dismissPopupRunnable);
}
```

**Note**, you have to take care of removing callbacks from handler, when activity is being paused.

Comment: What you mean by saying `popup window constantly running`?

Comment: I doesnt disapear at all.. Its there all the time

Comment: Because you have to do `popupWindow.dismiss()` in the part where there is written `// dismiss popupWindow()`.

Comment: Can you update the question with the implementation you did?